# Video Periodically freezes on Home Network

Tags: video, home-networking, freeze

I have a Windows 7 tower sharing video to my Xbox and Macbook laptop over a Gigabit / Wireless N home network (router is the linksys wireless N model).  Whenever I watch a video streamed from my tower to either the xbox or laptop, the movie freezes every few minutes.  The freezes last longer and longer until the video freezes for good.  What is going on here?  Is there some bottleneck in the router like a full cache file that needs to be cleaned or something?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a number of things, the most likely cause is signal strength on Wireless or a faulty cable if using wired. It could even be a bad router which simply cannot cope with high throughput.

The other causes are slow I/O on your machine where it cannot cache/send the video fast enough - however, it should not be getting worse as you go along.

How are you connected from device to device? If you are doing wireless to router, wireless to Xbox, I would highly recommend you just use a wire temporarily to rule out a problem with wireless.

Comment: To add to the point about wireless strength: inSSIDer is a useful tool for troubleshooting this (and seeing "competing" access points on the same channel) http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 has a powerful network monitor which is worth checking with.
Task Manager -> Performance -> Resource Monitor -> Network
You should be able to identify if anything else is clogging up the streaming on your PC side.